# Split text in specific order using common string "Message"

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, scripting, tr

I have a text file with following contents

```
$ cat foo.txt

some text 
email@id.com
8903457923
2018-02-09 07:12 (Asia/Kolkata)
again some text over here
some more text again
Message
some text 
email@id.com
8903457923
2018-02-05 07:12 (Asia/Kolkata)
again some text over here
some more text again
Message
```

I would like to get following output

```
$ cat foo.txt

some text  email@id.com  8903457923  2018-02-09 07:12 (Asia/Kolkata)  again some text over her  some more text again  Message

some text email@id.com  8903457923  2018-02-05 07:12 (Asia/Kolkata) again some text over here  some more text again  Message
```

I guess I can achive this using tr and taking "Message" as a common string.
But not sure how to implement this.

Comment: is the blank line between the two output data lines important?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the current line is not "Message", then append the line to the list, joined with OFS; when you see "Message", print the current list (joined by OFS with the current "Message" line):

```
awk '/^Message$/ { print t OFS $0 ORS; t=""; } !/^Message$/ { t=(t ? t OFS $0 : $0) }' < foo.txt
```

The `t=(t ? t OFS $0 : $0)` part is a ternary operator; it checks to see if `t` is empty; if it is, then just assign the current line to it; otherwise, append the current value with OFS followed by the current line.

Output:

```
some text  email@id.com 8903457923 2018-02-09 07:12 (Asia/Kolkata) again some text over here some more text again Message

some text  email@id.com 8903457923 2018-02-05 07:12 (Asia/Kolkata) again some text over here some more text again Message
```

Answer (score 5):

a bit easier way with AWK:

`awk 'BEGIN { ORS=RS="Message\n" } gsub("\n"," ")' ./in.txt`

Comment: note that not all versions support multi-character RS..

Answer (score 2):

Using `tr` and `sed`:

```
tr '\n' '\t' <foo.txt  | sed -e $'s/Message\\\t/Message\\\n\\\n/g'
```

This will convert all newlines to tabs and then add a two newlines after each occurrence of `Message`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed

```
sed ':A;/Message/!{N;bA};y/\n/ /;$!G' foo.txt
```

Get lines in pattern space until you see Message.
Replace each newline by blank space.
Add a blank line only if it's not the last.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most direct method is :

```
 perl -lpe '$\ = /^Message$/ ? "\n\n" : " "' foo.txt
```

or using `awk` it would be:

```
 awk 'ORS = /^Message$/ ? RS RS : " "'
```

Slurp the file, `-0777` then the whole file is a one large string upon which the regex `/(.*?)^(Message\n)/msg` is operated. The regex looks at the shortest chunk which abuts the `Message` line and stores the chunk in `$1` and the nessage line in `$2`. The chunk comprises newlines which are replaced globally by space and the result of this transformation `tr/\n/ /r` is delivered to `print`. The `while` loop keeps going so long as the chunk + message lines are to be found.

```
perl -ln -0777e 'print $1 =~ tr/\n/ /r, $2 while /(.*?)^(Message\n)/msg' foo.txt
```

We could use the `sed` tool to perform this job as shown here:

```
sed -e '
    $!N;G;s/\n/ /                ;# put 2 lines in pattern space
    / Message\n$/b               ;# one message block has been found
    s/\(.*\)\(.\)/\2\1/;D        ;# go back to read the next line into pattern space
' foo.txt
```